# Evolution of the amounts paid between two months

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, business-intelligence

Can someone help me to apply the right formula to show the evolution of the paid amounts between two months, for instance :

```
In february :
Paid amounts = 30 Dollars
Turnover = 100 dollars
Evolution of Paid amounts are :  30%


In March :
Paid amounts = 20 Dollars
Turnover = 100 dollars
Evolution of Paid amounts are :  20%
```

Which formula is right To show the evolution between MARCH and FEBRUARY ?

```
(Paid ( March ) - Paid ( February ) ) * 100 / Paid ( February )
```

or

```
Percentage ( March ) - Percentage ( Fabruary )
```

Thank you :)

Comment: The meaning of "evolution" is quite vague. Can you clarify it? What do you expect if the paid amount for February was 0? In the first formula, there is a division by zero, and in the second formula, it says that there is a 20% increase, but none of these result make sense to me.

Comment: It has to be `(Paid ( March ) - Paid ( February ) ) * 100 / Paid ( February )`, as you're talking about the evolution of paid amount between months!

Comment: Thank you so Much, so finally the correct formula is :    ( T1 - T0 ) * 100 / T0